# Java/Android if http page contains

Tags: java, android, http

I my code is currently like this where I save it to a file (which is nice for debugging and I just use code to read from the file however I can never find a match no matter how general it is

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                FileOutputStream outputStream;
                try {
                    outputStream = openFileOutput("HTMLOUTPUT.txt", getApplicationContext().MODE_PRIVATE);
                    HttpGet httpRequest = null;
                    httpRequest = new HttpGet(checkUrl.toURI());

                    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse) httpclient.execute(httpRequest);

                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    BufferedHttpEntity bufHttpEntity = new BufferedHttpEntity(entity);
                    bufHttpEntity.writeTo(outputStream);
                    outputStream.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        thread.start();
        File readFile = new File(this.getFilesDir(), "HTMLOUTPUT.txt");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(readFile);
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        stringBuilder.append("^.*\\b(");
        stringBuilder.append(wordsToFind);
        stringBuilder.append(")\\b.*$");
        Pattern findPattern = Pattern.compile(stringBuilder.toString());

        int lineNum = 0;

        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = scanner.nextLine();
            lineNum++;
            if(line.matches(findPattern.toString())) {
                Log.i("SHITFINDER","ho hum, i found it on line " +lineNum);
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: you want to read only txt file .this file is get from server?means any webservice or sdcard?

Comment: I would go for just about any solution. Right now I am pulling the html saving it as a text file just for simplicity and then I want to look for the string "wordsToFind"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're reading the file while it is still empty. There isn't any point in writing the file in a separate thread and then trying to read from it immediately while the file is still being written. Get rid of the thread, do the network stuff, write the file, close it, and then do your searching. Or indeed just search the file while you're downloading it, if you don't need to keep it.

Comment: in Android you aren't  allowed to do access network over the main thread. I am going to add a thread.join though right now.